# HTML5 blend two images while the one is moving

Tags: html5-canvas, blending

I have a code with two pictures,the backround picture and a smaller one that's moving random around the canvas. The small picture must be blended (without global alpha) while is moving.Do you have any idea? Here is what I did so far.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var context;
    var dx= 4;
    var dy=4;
    var y=150;
    var x=10;

    function draw(){
        var imageObj = document.getElementById("night");
        var imageObj2 = document.getElementById("small_image");
        context= myCanvas.getContext('2d');
        context.clearRect(0,0,1920,1200);
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
        context.drawImage(imageObj2, x, y);
        if( x<0 || x>1920-imageObj2.width)
        dx=-dx;
        if( y<0 || y>1200-imageObj2.height)
            dy=-dy;
            x+=dx;
            y+=dy;
        }
    setInterval(draw,10); 
    </script>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>It's Christmas Time</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="night" src="cartoon.jpg" alt="sima" width="300" height="200" hidden>
        <img id="small_image" src="small_image.gif" hidden>

        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1920" height="1200"></canvas>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused about what you're expecting to happen. Perhaps this is what you're trying to do?

```
var x = 0,
    y = 0,
    dx = 1,
    dy = 1;

function draw(){
      var imageObj = document.getElementById("night");
      var imageObj2 = document.getElementById("small_image");
      context= myCanvas.getContext('2d');
      context.clearRect(0,0,1920,1200);
      context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
      context.drawImage(imageObj2, x, y);
      if( x<0 || x > 1920 - imageObj2.width)
          dx = -dx;
      if( y < 0 || y > 1200 -imageObj2.height)
          dy = -dy;
      x += dx;
      y += dy;
}
setInterval(draw,10);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/avzn89ay/

Comment: Thanks for your replay :) I'm trying to make the snowflake blended.I mean I want to change it's color accoriding the position that it has.

Comment: Please clarify what "blend" means in your design. Is Blend one of the Photoshop blending modes: multiply, screen, etc.?

Comment: I don't know how it's called but I can try to explain you what i mean.I have a background image and one smaller image a snowflake. The snowflake is moving and I want to change the color.I want to have 50% it's color and 50% the color that is in the backround.

Comment: Perhaps this twist on Sam Greenhalgh's idea: http://jsfiddle.net/effg7bzb/.  This uses compositing to blend colors from the 2 images. In particular 'lighter' compositing will add the 2 colors together.

Comment: Now I realise that Sam Greenhalgh gave me what exactly I want. Thank you very much all of you.

Comment: And as a bonus, here's Nicolas Cage snow http://jsfiddle.net/z1g4bcsh/1/embedded/result/

Comment: @SamGreenhalgh Chuckle!

Comment: And one more question . Do you have any idea how can I do "blending" by changing the pixels in the code?

Comment: You could use getImageData and manipulate the pixel values - like this http://www.playmycode.com/blog/2011/06/realtime-image-tinting-on-html5-canvas/

Comment: I dont't have to use global aplha (it's a project an the teacher was strict about that). Can you help me to include this part of code into my code?